# Intellij Filewatcher, how to hard code what file to compile?

Tags: intellij-idea, less, file-watcher

I have got the same issue as the guy in this post: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206447829-File-watchers-issues-and-LESS

@Andriy Bazanov suggests to "hard code what file to compile". My question is, how do you do that?

This is what my settings currently looks like:
[image]

I would like it to always compile the root file upon detecting a change in the custom scope I specified. The root file it should compile is located at `C:\Users\...\react-designer\less\style.less`.

---

Currently, it seems to only recompile the file that is being changed, but I am not completely sure about this being the case.

Comment: you need to make sure that your `style.less` is included in scope, and that all the files you'd like to be 'merged' in the resultant CSS are included in this main `.less` file through imports

Comment: @lena (1) `style.less` is indeed included in the scope; I can confirm that by making a change in `styles.less` as that will trigger the filewatcher. (2) I am sure all ´.less` files are imported in the main `style.less` file through imports.  I can add some pictures to show this if you'd  like -- but I don't think it'll help much besides you being able to confirm that (1) and (2) is 100% not the issue.

Comment: this should work then - once you change your main file or one of the partials included in scope, the root file will be re-compiled